# Why we create new processes using fork() or exec() system calls?

Tags: process, fork, exec

As we are taught in the class that new processes are created using **fork()** or **exec()** system calls.

Suppose we created a child process using fork(), what is the purpose of this newly created process? why we created that process?

I am asking about the applications where we have to create a new process.

Answer (score 0):

A few example uses of creating new processes:

- In the shell environment, each command you run (like `ls`) is its own binary file. The main shell program will `fork()` and then execute the relevant utility.
- Web servers such as the Apache httpd server will create a new process using `fork()` to handle separate requests.
- Some web browsers, like Chrome, create new processes for each tab that's open, in order to take advantage of the isolation between separate processes to improve security.
- Desktop environments will fork and execute new processes each time you open an application through the GUI menu (such as the start menu in windows, or the dock in MacOS)
- Build systems such as make fork and execute compilers as separate processes when building your code.

There are many others, but these are *some* examples of when you might need to use multiple processes in a program.

Comment: Can we run a shell command without using fork() and any family of exec() system call?

Comment: Short answer -> not unless you wanted the program that called the shell command to close. Long answer -> it's _theoretically_ possible to find a way to do it. But it wouldn't be remotely platform independent, it wouldn't be worth doing, and it would be completely off the table for any shell command that includes two or more utilities at once.